# Best way to set JRE_HOME to Sun's Java on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java, ubuntu-10.04

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 which by default came with OpenJDK. I've since installed Sun's Java 6 using `apt-get`. When I type `java -version` I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

However, when I start Tomcat it still appears to using Open JDK.

```
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

What's the best way to globally point to Sun's Java? Is there a way to uninstall Open JDK?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the `update-alternatives` command? You would use it like this: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then choose the version you want.

See the [Ubuntu Java page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`update-alternatives` as canen mentioned is the way to go if you want to set the Java default for the whole system.

Regarding Tomcat on Ubuntu 10.04, I suggest taking a look at the [Tomcat page in the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/tomcat.html) especially the paragraph titled "Changing JVM used".

In short: change the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `/etc/default/tomcat6`.